# How can I increase my Docker Sonarqube disk space to avoid this warning?

Tags: jenkins, docker, sonarqube

I get the following output when running the SonarQube Scanner from Jenkins:

```
2016.02.23 11:01:00 INFO   es[o.e.c.r.a.decider]  [sonar-1456222793208] high disk watermark exceeded on one or more nodes, rerouting shards
2016.02.23 11:01:30 WARN   es[o.e.c.r.a.decider]  [sonar-1456222793208] high disk watermark [90%] exceeded on [VKGYodBwSRylFJ46lQT_xw][sonar-1456222793208] free: 436.6mb[2.3%], shards will be relocated away from this node
2016.02.23 11:02:00 WARN   es[o.e.c.r.a.decider]  [sonar-1456222793208] high disk watermark [90%] exceeded on [VKGYodBwSRylFJ46lQT_xw][sonar-1456222793208] free: 436.6mb[2.3%], shards will be relocated away from this node
2016.02.23 11:02:00 INFO   es[o.e.c.r.a.decider]  [sonar-1456222793208] high disk watermark exceeded on one or more nodes, rerouting shards
2016.02.23 11:02:30 WARN   es[o.e.c.r.a.decider]  [sonar-1456222793208] high disk watermark [90%] exceeded on [VKGYodBwSRylFJ46lQT_xw][sonar-1456222793208] free: 436.6mb[2.3%], shards will be relocated away from this node
```

As stated in the header, in addition if this warning is critical or if the Docker will expand itself (as I have read during my research)? However, I have not found an explicit answer or another peer having this specific problem or similar problem to me.

Docker info:

```
2016.02.23 11:01:00 INFO   es[o.e.c.r.a.decider]  [sonar-1456222793208] high disk watermark exceeded on one or more nodes, rerouting shards
2016.02.23 11:01:30 WARN   es[o.e.c.r.a.decider]  [sonar-1456222793208] high disk watermark [90%] exceeded on [VKGYodBwSRylFJ46lQT_xw][sonar-1456222793208] free: 436.6mb[2.3%], shards will be relocated away from this node
2016.02.23 11:02:00 WARN   es[o.e.c.r.a.decider]  [sonar-1456222793208] high disk watermark [90%] exceeded on [VKGYodBwSRylFJ46lQT_xw][sonar-1456222793208] free: 436.6mb[2.3%], shards will be relocated away from this node
2016.02.23 11:02:00 INFO   es[o.e.c.r.a.decider]  [sonar-1456222793208] high disk watermark exceeded on one or more nodes, rerouting shards
2016.02.23 11:02:30 WARN   es[o.e.c.r.a.decider]  [sonar-1456222793208] high disk watermark [90%] exceeded on [VKGYodBwSRylFJ46lQT_xw][sonar-1456222793208] free: 436.6mb[2.3%], shards will be relocated away from this node
```

Docker version:

```
2016.02.23 11:01:00 INFO   es[o.e.c.r.a.decider]  [sonar-1456222793208] high disk watermark exceeded on one or more nodes, rerouting shards
2016.02.23 11:01:30 WARN   es[o.e.c.r.a.decider]  [sonar-1456222793208] high disk watermark [90%] exceeded on [VKGYodBwSRylFJ46lQT_xw][sonar-1456222793208] free: 436.6mb[2.3%], shards will be relocated away from this node
2016.02.23 11:02:00 WARN   es[o.e.c.r.a.decider]  [sonar-1456222793208] high disk watermark [90%] exceeded on [VKGYodBwSRylFJ46lQT_xw][sonar-1456222793208] free: 436.6mb[2.3%], shards will be relocated away from this node
2016.02.23 11:02:00 INFO   es[o.e.c.r.a.decider]  [sonar-1456222793208] high disk watermark exceeded on one or more nodes, rerouting shards
2016.02.23 11:02:30 WARN   es[o.e.c.r.a.decider]  [sonar-1456222793208] high disk watermark [90%] exceeded on [VKGYodBwSRylFJ46lQT_xw][sonar-1456222793208] free: 436.6mb[2.3%], shards will be relocated away from this node
```

I am using SonarQube version 5.3.

Comment: This looks like an ElasticSearch log entry.

Answer (score 0):

The size of each container is limited depending on the version of your docker usually to 10G.
You can change this setting when starting docker daemon. The option depends on your storage driver - here's an example for devicemapper:

```
docker daemon --storage-opt dm.basesize=50G
```

More info can be found in the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/daemon/#storage-driver-options)